# How to downgrade plugin?

Tags: plugins

I have installed a plugin, but it causes problem with get_the_excerpt() function in my theme. So, I need to downgrade that plugin. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "*downgrade* the Plugin"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that plugin is hosted on wordpress.org, go to the plugin page, click on the **developers** tab, and select an older version. [Example for JetPack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/developers/).